# Cloudwatch Event Rule doesn't invoke when source state machine fails

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that runs 2 separate lambdas. If the step function fails or times out, I want to get an email via SNS telling me the step function failed.  I created the event rule using cloudformation and specified the statemachine ARN in the event pattern.  When the step function fails, no email is sent out.  If I remove the stateMachineArn parameter and run my step function, I get the failure email.  I've double checked numerous times that I'm entering the correct ARN for the state machine.  CF for the Event Rule is below (in YAML format).  Thanks.

```
  FailureEvent:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    DependsOn:
      - StateMachine
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref FailureRuleName
      Description: "EventRule"
      EventPattern:
        detail-type:
          - "Step Functions Execution Status Change"
        detail:
          status:
            - "FAILED"
            - "TIMED_OUT"
        stateMachineArn: ["arn:aws:states:region:account#:stateMachine:statemachine"]
      Targets:
        -
          Arn:
            Ref: SNSARN
          Id: !Ref SNSTopic
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with SUCCEEDED status, did you find an answer?

Comment: It's working for me, make sure you are using an existing ARN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get this fixed and expanded on it to invoke a lambda that publishes a custom SNS email using a lambda.  My alignment was off in my EventPattern section.  See below.  Thanks to @Marcin.

```
FailureEvent:
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
DependsOn:
  - FMIStateMachine
Properties:
  Description: !Ref FailureRuleDescription
  Name: !Ref FailureRuleName
  State: "ENABLED"
  RoleArn:
    'Fn::Join': ["", ['arn:aws:iam::', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', ':role/', !Ref LambdaExecutionRole]]
  EventPattern:
    detail-type:
      - "Step Functions Execution Status Change"
    detail:
      status:
        - "FAILED"
        - "TIMED_OUT"
      stateMachineArn: [!Ref StateMachine]
  Targets:
    - Arn:
        'Fn::Join': ["", ['arn:aws:lambda:', !Ref 'AWS::Region', ':', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', ':function:', !Ref FailureLambda]]
      Id: !Ref FailureLambda
      Input: !Sub '{"failed_service": "${StateMachineName}","sns_arn": "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${SNSTopic}"}'
```